# create text file on the fly and ask user to download

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

is it possible to create a text file "on the fly" and then ask the client to download it?

i only have two options available to me:
1. javascript
2. asp classic

which of these 2 can do this?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: Why create a text file?  Why not simply send text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classic ASP by creating a text file on disk then redirecting to the text file. Note that the file in this example `test.txt` is created in the folder where the page lives (E.G., \inetpub\wwwroot, etc.)

```
<%
Dim fs, fname

Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fname = fs.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("test.txt"), true)

fname.WriteLine("Hello World!")
fname.Close

Set fname = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

Response.Redirect("text.txt")
%>
```

Comment: You can also stream the file to the user to force download.  Combine it with a javascript front end that makes an ajax call to create the file, and you have a good example .